# sharepoint 2010 central administration not starting after install

Tags: sharepoint

After installing sharepoint server 2010 on server 2008 64 bit . every thing goes well no errors,but after clicking sharepoint server 2010 central administration from the program menu i got this message

The version of this file compatible with the version of windows you you're running .Check yourf computer system information to see whether u need an x86 or x65 version of the program , and then contact the software publisher

browser issue? what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch a few times the configuration wizard in sql server and in your SP server and it will come back.

It worked for me